# Kendoui Mobile customer validation action

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am creating a mobile site using Kendoui mobile and using KendoValidation. 
The problem is that by default the error messages block the input area's due to the small display area.

One thought I have is to just change the color of the prompt to red when a input is invalid and, if needed, a tooltip that will display when the input as focus.

Is there a way to stop the messages and get perform this action?

Thanks, George

Answer (score 2):

I found my own solution:

Instantiated the validator using:

```
var validator=$('#mt-New-Reservation').kendoValidator({ errorTemplate: "" }).data('kendoValidator');
```

and added the following css:

```
.k-invalid {background-color: lightpink !important;}
```

The errorTemplate: "" causes the error message to not display.
The validator adds a class k-invalid to any item that is not valid, so the css changes the background color of the input area.

For my application, most of the inputs as self-explanatory and do not need a detailed message (most of the time the 'required' rule is what's making it invalid). So just changing the background color draws the used's attention to the item that needs to be fixed.

-George